# How to replace a loop that looks at multiple previous values with a formula in Python

Tags: python, database, pandas, loops

**My Problem**

I have a loop that creates a column using either a formula based on values from other columns or the previous value in the column depending on a condition ("days from new low == 0"). It is really slow over a huge dataset so I wanted to get rid of the loop and find a formula that is faster.

**Current Working Code**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

csv1 = pd.read_csv('stock_price.csv', delimiter = ',')
df = pd.DataFrame(csv1)

for x in range(1,len(df.index)):
    if df["days from new low"].iloc[x] == 0:
        df["mB"].iloc[x] = (df["RSI on new low"].iloc[x-1] - df["RSI on new low"].iloc[x]) / -df["days from new low"].iloc[x-1]
    else:
        df["mB"].iloc[x] = df["mB"].iloc[x-1]

df
```

**Input Data and Expected Output**

```
RSI on new low,days from new low,mB
0,22,0
29.6,0,1.3
29.6,1,1.3
29.6,2,1.3
29.6,3,1.3
29.6,4,1.3
21.7,0,-2.0
21.7,1,-2.0
21.7,2,-2.0
21.7,3,-2.0
21.7,4,-2.0
21.7,5,-2.0
21.7,6,-2.0
21.7,7,-2.0
21.7,8,-2.0
21.7,9,-2.0
25.9,0,0.5
25.9,1,0.5
25.9,2,0.5
23.9,0,-1.0
23.9,1,-1.0
```

**Attempt at Solution**

```
def mB_calc (var1,var2,var3):
    df[var3]= np.where(df[var1] == 0, df[var2].shift(1) - df[var2] / -df[var1].shift(1) , "")
    return df

df = mB_calc('days from new low','RSI on new low','mB')
```

First, it gives me this "TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'" and second I dont know how to incorporate the "ffill" into the formula.

Any idea how I might be able to do it?

Cheers!

Comment: 2nd line of provided data only has 2 values. Typo?

Comment: `np.where(...)` is your friend

Comment: IcedLance thanks for the spot. I just corrected it. Polka, i tried with where which i have now put into the post but i didnt have any joy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```py
df["mB_temp"] = (df["RSI on new low"].shift() - df["RSI on new low"]) / -df["days from new low"].shift()
df["mB"] = df["mB"].shift()
df["mB"].loc[df["days from new low"] == 0]=df["mB_temp"].loc[df["days from new low"] == 0]
df.drop(["mB_temp"], axis=1)
```

And with `np.where`:

```py
df["mB"] = np.where(df["days from new low"]==0, df["RSI on new low"].shift() - df["RSI on new low"]) / -df["days from new low"].shift(), df["mB"].shift())
```

Comment: Thank you for your post. it returns the correct value on rows where "days from new low" == 0 but all other rows are "NaN". I added df['mB'] = df['mB'].ffill()  to the end and to seems to work now. However, I have the extra column mB_Temp which isnt ideal

Comment: I think you need to add .loc to the right part too: `df["mB"].loc[df["days from new low"] == 0]=df["mB_temp"].loc[df["days from new low"] == 0]`

Comment: do you know how i could re-write using np.where ?

Comment: I added ```np.where``` version. Also - you drop ```mB_temp``` in last line of my original code.